# Console app C# declare static global const variable at runtime args best practices

Tags: c#, oop, console-application

In a C# console application, I want to be able to set values at run-time which will stay constant and globally accessible throughout the life-cycle of the program.

The app must be able to accept arguments on execution and be scheduled to do this.
E.g. at 10:00am execute app with args name="john", at 11:00am execute again with name="jane".

The name variable should not be editable once run and it should be accessible by any class once run.

My question is - what is the best way to set and store this variable at runtime?

Comment: Marking a property as `readonly` means that it cannot be changed after initialised, and can only be initialised in the constructor. Might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Immutable singleton class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Create your field  `readonly` and initialize it from the constructor like so:

```
class myClass
{
   public static readonly myField;
   ... // the rest of your fields and get/set methods;
   public myClass(string myField)
   {
      this.MyField = myField; 
   }
}
```